# Perform a join on a collection only WHERE substring matches

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I would like to perform a join on a collection where student name are equal in each collection AND WHERE the last string after **"_"** in column **log's** value is what the variable **id** is.

I got the join to work but the issue is on the match statement. How can I match with a substring of a string on the **logs** column in the collection that I am about to join?

I can split the log column value into an array like this:

```
{ $split: [ "$studentInfo.log", "_" ]}
```

I just need to get the last value after underscore now to match variable **id**

```
var id = "123";

dbo.collection("student").aggregate([
{ "$lookup": {
    "localField": "name",
    "from": "data",
    "foreignField": "data.studentName",
    "as": "studentInfo"
}
}]).toArray(function(err, results) {
    console.log(results);
});
```

The issue is that student name is not unique so in order to get the join to work correctly we need to join by name AND make sure the characters after underscore match with the variable we have **id**

student collection

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("(Object ID here"),
    "name": "Test"
}
```

data collection

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("(Object ID here"),
    "studentName": "Test",
    "log": "NC_Test_123"
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("(Object ID here"),
    "studentName": "Test",
    "log": "FC_Test_444"
}
```

I need to get `NC_Test_123` when the variable I have for id is 123.

Comment: Could you show sample documents from both collections ?

Comment: @mickl edited the post. Please check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define custom [lookup condition](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#join-conditions-and-uncorrelated-sub-queries) with both conditions: student name and `log` field. To get the last value of splitted string you can use [$arrayElemAt](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt/index.html) with index set to `-1`

```
db.student.aggregate([
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "data",
            let: { "student_name": "$name" },
            pipeline: [
                {
                    $match: {
                        $expr: {
                            $and: [
                                { $eq: [ "$$student_name", "$studentName" ] },
                                { $eq: [ { $arrayElemAt: [ { $split: [ "$log", "_" ]}, -1 ] }, "123" ] }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                }
            ],
            as: "studentInfo"
        }
    },
    {
        $unwind: "$studentInfo"
    }
])
```